# Receive Instagram likes and comment count without API in PHP

Tags: php, api, instagram

I need to retrieve the like and comment count on the recent posts of Instagram accounts without using the Instagram API. Preferably the likes and comments on the second, third and fourth latest post or be able to get the posts if they are older than a day or something.

I am currently using this script to get the like and comment count:

```
//Information URL
$rawurl = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/username'); 

//Latest Likes
preg_match('/\"likes\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-9]+)/',$rawurl,$likestring);
$likes = intval($likestring[1]);    

//Latest Comments
preg_match('/\"comments\"\:\s?\{\"count\"\:\s?([0-
9]+)/',$rawurl,$commentstring);
$comments = intval($commentstring[1]);
```

Although I can't work out how to get it from other posts such as their second, third and fourth recent posts. I would prefer this to be all done from their profile page (like this instagram.com/username) rather than a picture page (like this instagram.com/p/code).

Thanks for any help

(Edit: I'd also like it if there was an easy way to alter the code I shared above so it could get other posts rather than just the latest one)

Comment: Why without the api?

Comment: @Terminus because that means I'll have to get the application approved and I'll have to create a video for the process. Since this is a small project I didn't want to go through all that effort but it seems like I might

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to use cURL if you want to do that. That can be a process of trial and error. I'm not an Instagram user so I can't tell you how easy or difficult that is, it kinds of depends on the site and how difficult they make it. You might also want to explore some other screen scraping projects out there to  help you out.

Comment: Okay thanks for that, I'll definitely look into cURL. Do you know any way to alter the code I shared above to get other posts?

Comment: If there is a "next page" button, you might be able to extract the URL from that. But again, I'm not an Instagram user so you'll have to poke around in the View Source once a page loads.